# Error when i install pip in python2.7 in window

Tags: python-2.7, pip

i am try to install pip for Django in python2.7(window7) when i try to run
python get-pip.py i get error in cmd.

**python get-pip.py**

*could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip no matching distribution found for pip*

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to a newer version of python.

Refer: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5357